# Is it possible to override built-in operators in Scala?

Tags: scala, operator-overloading

This is rather a hypothetical question, but let's say I'd like to change the behaviour of `+` (or any other arithmetic operator) on `Int` within a scope, something like this (I know it is something crazy and is something I'd try to avoid in general, but I find it interesting):

```
object MySillyStuff extends App {
  def +(a: Int, b: Int) = a*b;

  println(1+2)
}
```

Is that possible this way, or I'm only able to overload operators through implicit conversions with a new type? (I.e., I have to explicitly create `1` as a member of that new type and use implicit conversion of `2` for that specific type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that there are no operators in scala. In the question `+` is the method of `Int`: `(1).+(2)`.

The only way to override an existing method is inheritance with `override` keyword.

Implicit class allows you to add a new method, but not to override the method that already is there.

You could wrap your class without overhead using [value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html#summary_of_limitations) like this:

```
case class StrangeInt(val i: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def +(that: Int): StrangeInt = StrangeInt(i*that)
}

val i = StrangeInt(3)
println(i+3)
// StrangeInt(9)
```

Comment: Ok, so basically I cannot do that. Thought there is some hack though through overriding things in `Predef` or something but haven't seen any operators there. Thx for the clarification, senia!

Comment: @rlegendi: there are no operators in scala. `+` is the method of `Int`: `(1).+(2)`. It has nothing with `Predef`.

Comment: Can you prove in your example that multiplication happened, instead of addition? ;-)

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet: `2*2` is `4`, so there should be no doubt it was multiplication. Yes, I've failed with example. =)